# Proxy Server (Java): queuing requests

Tags: java, multithreading, proxy, queuing

I need to create a proxy server, which:

- receives many queries;
- sends them to external system in bulk;
- gets a response;
- returns response to clients.

It looks like following:

```
{Req_A}, {Req_B}, {Req_C}, {Req_D}, {Req_E} -> Proxy -> {Req A, B, C}, {Req D, E}

{Resp A, B, C}, {Resp D, E} -> Proxy -> {Resp_A}, {Resp_B}, {Resp_C}, {Resp_D}, {Resp_E}
```

I hope you get the idea.

**My question**

Is there existing frameworks to handle the case? If there are none, what would be optimal design for the problem?

Comment: Maybe http://nodejs.org is an interesting option.

Comment: I definitely need it to be done in **JAVA**.

Comment: Just because I'm curious: Is this a technical requirement (e.g. must be integrated into an existing java system), due to personal preferences, or a management decision (e.g. everything else is written in java, so this must be java too)?

Comment: Because those requests coming through an infrastructure, done in Java. Those are not HTTP requests!

Comment: Not exactly sure but try taking a look at [Netty](http://netty.io) or, at a higher level, [Finagle](https://twitter.github.io/finagle/). Good luck!